Mongo db isn't updating my profile, I have tried markModified
Hello I have this problem where my profile isn't updating so when I use the function in discord it just spams I've tried marking tasks as modified but that isn't working either, any other things I could try? It finds the profile just well and does the changes when I log it but when its time to update it just forgets everything and doesn't update
    async function reward(userID, task, interaction) {
  try {
    let profile = await profileModel.findOne({ user: userID });

    let profileTaskIndex = profile.tasks.findIndex((v) => v.name === task.name);
    if (profileTaskIndex === -1) return;

    profile.tasks.splice(profileTaskIndex, 1);

    if (task.rewardType === "item") {
      let found = items.find((v) => v.name === task.reward);
      if (!found) return;
      profile = await giveItem(userID, task.reward, profile);
    } else if (task.rewardType === "coins") profile.coins += task.reward;

    profile.markModified("tasks");
    await profile.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


The main issue can be that you are modifying the profile object in-place without ensuring it is fully tracked by Mongoose for changes.
Try out the below code and let me know whether it has resolved your query or not:

    async function reward(userID, task, interaction) {
      try {
        let update = {
          $pull: { tasks: { name: task.name } }
        };
    
        if (task.rewardType === "item") {
          let found = items.find((v) => v.name === task.reward);
          if (!found) return;
          await giveItem(userID, task.reward);
        } else if (task.rewardType === "coins") {
          update.$inc = { coins: task.reward };
        }
    
        await profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: userID },
          update,
          { new: true }
        );
    
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }


I hope this will resolve your query.

There are no changes here, I have already marked tasks as modified but it doesn't work.

If you are marking the tasks as modified but it is not working, then the issue might be due to Mongoose is not recognizing other parts of the document as modified.
Ok, no worry I am modifying the code in the answer, just check again.
I am using "profile.markModified("coins")" to track the changes and instead of using "splice()" I am using "filter()" to create new array.

Still doesn't update, it saves the changes but it doesn't update them. Like tasks is removing the object from the array but its not updating so it just stays there.

If the tasks are not updating even after being removed then it means that either Mongoose is not detecting the modification correctly or the database operation is not committed as expected.
To overcome this problem a you can try one more approach to directly update the document in MongoDB instead of relying on Mongoose's in memory tracking.

I am updating the code once again try that code and let me know again if you face any difficulties.

still doesn't work
